# How Flutter adds a top-level view (similar to iOS adding to a window)

Tags: flutter

[image]
The widget is always displayed on the screen, just like in iOS, adding controls to the window. How to achieve it, thank you! Grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your MaterialApp to remove it

```
MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
)
```

Comment: No, I want to write a component like this, which is always suspended in the window layer of the APP. How to do it, do you know?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Banner widget that actually displays debug banner.

docs link : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Banner-class.html

```
 Banner(
          location: BannerLocation.topEnd,
          message: "",
          child: Icon(Icons.help), //you can pass anything here as widget
          color: Colors.transparent,
        ),
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but the effect I need is like this. I am sorry that it is my problem and the requirement is not clear

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Stack` Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) to overlay Widgets over one another. For example:

```dart
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    Container(
      width: 90,
      height: 90,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    Container(
      width: 80,
      height: 80,
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
  ],
)
```

The [Banner](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Banner-class.html) widget realises this by creating a [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html), take a look at the [Implementation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/banner.dart). But I think a Stack would be the better choice here if you are using Widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this. Flutter provides a default `Banner` widget.It is somewhat similar to the debug banner what we are used to of seeing on the top-right corner on a flutter app in debug mode.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Banner-class.html